# Swift Firebase querying

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to grab the uid given his email.

I have this:

```
let usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("users")

    usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryStarting(atValue: email).queryEnding(atValue: email).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let values = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]{
            print(values)
        }
    })
```

And my database looks as follows:

users

|
-$uid

|
--email: "some email"

The snapshot doesn't return anything.

Also, the debugger tells me this:

> Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "email" at /users to your security rules for better performance

I think I have done this like so:

```
{
  "rules": {
"users": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
    ".indexOn": ["email"]
  }
```

But this doesn't work as well.

Comment: What is the expected output? please explain what is the purpose of query?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Try this : `usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue:email).observeSingleEvent`

Comment: It's hard to be certain what's happening without seeing the exact JSON. Can you get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data) and add it to your question?

Comment: Thanks, 3stud1ant3, that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define Firebase Database indexes in the location where you execute the query. So that is one level higher than where you currently have it:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": ["email"],
      ".read": "auth != null",
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change like below :

```
{
    "rules": {
    "users": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".indexOn": "email"
    }
    }
}
```